# IndentationError: unexpected indent after comment

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

I am trying to write some Python example code with a line commented out:

```
user_by_email = session.query(User)\
    .filter(Address.email=='one')\
    #.options(joinedload(User.addresses))\
    .first()
```

I also tried:

```
user_by_email = session.query(User)\
    .filter(Address.email=='one')\
#    .options(joinedload(User.addresses))\
    .first()
```

But I get IndentationError: unexpected indent.
If I remove the commented out line, the code works.
I am decently sure that I use only spaces (Notepad++ screenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose the statement in parentheses.

```
user_by_email = (session.query(User)
     .filter(Address.email=='one')
     #.options(joinedload(User.addresses))
     .first())
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially its the same line , thats how Python interpreter reads it.

Just like you can not comment just a word in line of code. (Below)

> Not allowed

```
user_by_email = session.query(User).filter(Address.email=='one')#comment#.first()
```

You need to move the comment to the end of the line.

```
user_by_email = session.query(User)\
    .filter(Address.email=='one')\
    .first()
#.options(joinedload(User.addresses))\
```

Comment: removing the slash didn't work but adding braces did.

Comment: @Prateek I removed my comment as I could not edit it to correct that the simple removal of the backslash does not work in that case.

Comment: sorry , i thought that worked .updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
user_by_email = session.query(User).\
filter(Address.email=='one').\
#options(joinedload(User.addresses)).\
first()
```

Comment: Then I get: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character